# Ошибка в регистрации со стороны сервера

Tags: php

С стороны сервера я имею такой код:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array("SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id_pok = '".$_GET['startpoke']."'")  or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (img,name_poke,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUE('".$row['img']."',".$row['name_poke']."',".$row['life']."',".$row['atk']."',".$row['def']."',".$row['exp']."',".$row['type']."') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

И мне вы выбивает такую ошибку:

*Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:xampphtdocsstyleregister.php on line 49
Error:*

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать =)

Comment: Черт побери, мне бы такое упорство!=)

Comment: Вспомни себя на стадии начала изучения) а еще когда начало что-то получаться то апше)

Comment: Вспоминаю себя, начинал учить `php+mysql+mysql+html`. За 3 года 2 книги и 1 вопрос на `javascript.ru` по кроссбраузерности, остальное гугл, mysql.ru и php.net. А вот азарт был, да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id_pok = '".$_GET['startpoke']."'")  or die ('Error:'.mysql_error());

if(mysql_fetch_row($query) < 1)
{
  echo 'нет такого покемона';
}

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  echo $row['img'];
  // и т.д.
}
```

Comment: с помощью mysql_fetch_array делается вывод запроса, но не осуществляется запрос!

Comment: Абсолютная истина...<br>
Вам сначало нужно сделать сам запрос, например что-то типа<br>
<pre><code>
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
// а теперь уже можно fetch'ить
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
</pre></code>

Comment: И да - ненадо везде писать mysql_error... Напиши ты уже функцию хотябы типа <br>
<pre><code>
function query($query) {
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
</pre></code>
Ато если и доведешь все это когда-то до путя я себе представляю как тебе будет весело потом везде убирать mysql_query :D

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего надо так:

```
$startpoke = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['startpoke']);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id_pok = '$startpoke'")  or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res)  or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO startpoke (img,name_poke,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUE('".$row['img']."',".$row['name_poke']."',".$row['life']."',".$row['atk']."',".$row['def']."',".$row['exp']."',".$row['type']."') ") or die(mysql_error());
```